# How to get output using thread like below?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class CubaThread extends Thread { 
  public CubaThread (String s) { 
    super(s); 
  }
  public void run() { 
  int num;
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter +ve number: "); 
    num = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
    for (int i=1;i<5;i++){
         System.out.println("Olla I am "+getName()+i);
    try{
    Thread.sleep(10);
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e){
    }
  } 
}
}
public class Cuba{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        new CubaThread("Thread #").start();
    }
}
```

Below is the output I want:

```
Enter +ve number:
4

Hello, I am Thread #1

Hello, I am Thread #4

Hello, I am Thread #2

Hello, I am Thread #3
```

Here's what I'm actually getting:

```
Enter +ve number:
4

Hello, I am Thread #1

Hello, I am Thread #2

Hello, I am Thread #3

Hello, I am Thread #4
```

Comment: Pls paste the text here instead of the images, then ... take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Finally please read this [question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have each thread do the same task, and only have the name change between the threads, like so:

```
class CubaThread extends Thread { 
  public CubaThread (String s) { 
    super(s); 
  }
  public void run() {
    try {
      Thread.sleep(10);
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Olla I am "+getName());
  }
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println("Enter +ve number: ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    // you can declare num on the same line that it is initialized
    int num = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        new CubaThread("Thread #"+i).start();
  }
}
```

Example input:

```
Enter +ve number:
4
```

Example output:

```
Olla I am Thread #2
Olla I am Thread #0
Olla I am Thread #3
Olla I am Thread #1
```

Comment: I want the output below 5 and it wont become like that if it less than 10

Comment: You can add a sleep to the `run` method. I've edited my example

Comment: @Charlie In any case, it's kind of unpredictable depending on your OS, computer speed, and JVM. On my build (openjdk version "11.0.4" 2019-07-16) and a Linux distribution running on a laptop, it works fine (even without the `sleep` call).